# Get the id of clicked option in a select

Tags: jquery

```
HTML:
<select id="leftpane" size="10">
    <option id="1" value="one">One</option>
    <option id="2" value="two">Two</option>
</select>

jQuery:
$("#leftpane").click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

In the above code, if I click an item, it will display the id of the select that is "leftpane".  What I want is the id of the option that was clicked.  I can easily get the value:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

But how do I get the id of the option clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the `change` event instead; it gets triggered whenever a new option is selected:

```
$("#leftpane").on('change', function () {
    var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].id;
});
```

Inside the event handler, you use `this.options[this.selectedIndex]` to find the selected `<option>` element.

Comment: I like this as it is spot on with the this.options[this.selectedIndex].id and doesn't need extra jQuery selection. However I will stick with the click event as it is what I want even though the change event gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the selector to choose the `option`s.  This will cause the event handler to be assigned to options instead of the drop down.

```
$("#leftpane option").click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/hJdpV/

Comment: Three different answers. Yours have an event on each option. Any pros/cons?

Comment: I believe the others are just omitting the event handler.

Comment: Yes, but that is implied, like my original code, where there are only one event handler on the select tag and not on each option tag. I like your way as it is very straight forward, but with hundreds of option tags and an event handler on each, I feel maybe one event handler on the select tag and getting the id like $(':selected', this).prop('id') may be better. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#leftpane option:selected").prop('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use following code to get selected elements Id.

```
$("#leftpane").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
});

OR

$("#leftpane").click(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this is working i have tried .......... 

` $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#leftpane option").click(function () {
        alert(this.id);
          });
    }); `
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :)

```js
$("#leftpane option").click(function() {
    var clickedOptText = $(this).text();
    alert(clickedOptText)
});
```

OR

```js
$("#leftpane option").on("click",function(){

   var clickedText = $(this).text();
   alert(clickedText);
   var clickedValue = $(this).value();
     alert(clickedValue);

});
```